# how to append string when match by awk or sed

Tags: match

i need to append text when string matching like below ,

search string "Date_of_event"

my file
Date_of_event,
Account_IMSI,
Used_quantity_1,
Subscriber_Type,
Free_Call,

the Required Result
Date_of_event "dd/mm/yyyy hr24:mi:ss" ,

i need to replace the comma also to be at the end of line like above

Comment: Im already tried this ,   
sed "/Date_Of_Event,/ s|$| dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss,|" my_file     

but i got 2 commas 

 Date_Time_Of_Event, dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss,

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/Date_Of_Event,/Date_Of_Event dd\/mm\/yyyy hh24:mi:ss,\"/g' my_file
```

But you could also use different delim in sed, so you don't have to escape `/`

```
sed 's#Date_Of_Event,#Date_Of_Event dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss,\"#g' my_file
```